# Adding mysql row to end of href in a table

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, href

I am trying to add the content of a cell in a mysql row at the end of href in a table

This works without the row being added to the end of the href. Its a while loop so I wrapped the whole loop in a php bracket

```
echo "<td><a href=\"https://website/call?\">" . $row['TXID'] . "</a></td>";
```

But when I try to add in the "TXID" it errors out and the page doesnt load. I have tried a few solutions on here which lead me to escaping the \" for the href but im not sure why it isnt working.

```
echo "<td><a href=\"https://website/call?' . $row['TXID'] . '\">" . $row['TXID'] . "</a></td>";
```

Is it just my syntax that is wrong or am I missing something?

I apologize if this is a duplicate. I couldnt find anything for this exact situation that worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have syntax error try this

```
echo "<td><a href='https://website/call?{$row['TXID']} '>" . $row['TXID'] . "</a></td>";
```

Comment: You sir are a hero. I pulled out my hair for nearly an hour with this. Ill check back in 4 minutes when I can accept your answer. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

```
echo "<td><a href=\"https://website/call?".$row['TXID']."\">" . $row['TXID'] . "</a></td>";
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I saw the other solution first so ill be accepting that. But thank you so much for the quick response.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '<td><a href="https://website/call?"'.$row['TXID'].'">' . $row['TXID'] . '</a></td>';
```

This will work fine.
Use some kind of IDE, so that all your syntax errors and typo will be eliminated at the time of typing.I use netbeans ide 8.It is super cool for developing php applications.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the tip! That will come in handy in the future :)